# How to send push notification to specific group using onesignal in React Native?

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, onesignal

I get a problem using onesignal, I try to create Chatting App using React Native and for push notification use onesignal, for sending to the specific user is ok, but I get a problem when sending push notif to the specific group, this functions for send to a specific user :

```
createNotif() {
    var message = { 
      app_id: "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx.....",
      contents: {"en": "English Message"},
      include_player_ids: ["yyyy-yyyy-yyy....."],
      android_group: "mychat",
      android_group_message: {"en": "You have $[notif_count] new messages"}
    };

    fetch('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(message),
    });
  }
```

Please anyone gives me an example how to send push notif to the specific group.

Thanks